# Can't delete a set of Nodes in document from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml, rss

I'm trying to remove nodes from a rss document on a webpage.

I want to go from:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>

 <title></title>
 <link></link>
 <description></description>

 <item>
  <title>53w5</title>
  <link>est</link>
  <description></description>      
 </item>

</channel>
</rss>
```

To:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
 <channel>

 <title></title>
 <link></link>
 <description></description>

</channel>
</rss>
```

It's just to delete the item (and all his child).

This is my function to load the XML:

```
function loadXMLDoc(dname) {

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else {
            xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xhttp.open("GET", dname, false);
        xhttp.send("");
        return xhttp.responseXML;
    }
```

This is the code I have to delete the block:

```
    xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("rssFeed.xml");        
    it = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");        
    it.parentNode.removeChild(it);
```

I always they the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'removeChild' of undefined" when run it in Chrome. My xml file load proprely as I can see it in the network after the resquest.

Help will be much appreciated.

Antoine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var it = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");

for (var i = it.length; i--; )
    it[i].parentNode.removeChild(it[i]);
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I tried something similar as a previous solution by I had a syntax error.